# PowerShell Function return two True's

Tags: powershell

So at the end of my function I do:

```
    $assemblyVersionLine -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)"

    $assemblyVersion = $matches[0]

    $true 
    $assemblyVersion
}
```

Prior to this there are only assignments.

The result variable:

```
$result
```

Has these values:

```
True
True
1.0.0.0
```

Why?

I expect only

```
True
1.0.0.0
```

Comment: `$assemblyVersionLine -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)"` return `True` and `$true` return `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell automatically outputs any value it encounters which is not explicitly suppressed. Moreover, the `-match` operator used in this line:

```
$assemblyVersionLine -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)"
```

returns a boolean value (`True`) which is not suppressed, so PowerShell outputs it. The other `True` is coming from the `$true` on the line by itself.

---

You can suppress the first `True` by redirecting the result to `$null`:

```
$assemblyVersionLine -match "(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\d+\.)(\*|\d+)" > $null
```

Now you will only have one `True` outputted from the `$true` line.

Comment: Right, thought it was... this is only thing about powershell which is driving me nuts.... do you have to do `> $null` for any function that returns a value that you do not use a.k.a `Test-Path`

Comment: @CallumLinington - If it's on a line by itself and you don't want it outputted, yes. You can also cast to `[void]` or pipe to `Out-Null` (the last one isn't very efficient though). Variable assignment also suppresses output.